# Eclipse "Build Automatically" not cascading

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I have a project in Eclipse (Indigo but similar in Helios) which has files in `src/main/resources` which get processed to generate *.java source files in `target/generated-sources/xyz`. The project settings have "Build Automatically" enabled so whenever these resource files are edited and saved the corresponding `*.java` files are generated. I've added `target/generated-sources/xyz` to the projects Build Paths. This all works perfectly.

The problem is that the changes to the generated `*.java` files are inconsistently rebuilt. If I have one of those files open in the editor, then it notices that it changed and asks if I want to reload it. Reloading the `*.java` files is enough for it to recognize that it has changed and trigger a rebuild. If I don't have it open then it doesn't automatically pick up the changes.

Any ideas on what I can do to let Eclipse (Indigo preferably) know that these generated files are being updated? Or better yet tell it to monitor those folders directly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try configuring Eclipse to automatically refresh. I'm not sure about Indigo, but in Helios, it's in *Preferences → General → Workspace → Refresh Automatically.*

---

Here it is in Indigo:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: There you go! That seems to have done it. In Indigo there are two options now: "Refresh using native hooks or polling" and :Refresh on access". Playing with which is better but it appears that once it refreshes it picks it up and rebuilds. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I just remembered I have a dormant copy of Indigo. I'm not sure which of the new options is better. No idea why Eclipse doesn't automatically refresh by default.

Comment: Perhaps because someone could lose changes I guess. I am often outside the IDE so I like having it stay in sync. For me (on OS X) "Refresh on access" seems to work instantaneously. The other seems to be on a short but noticeable polling cycle. **Edit:** scratch that. Just setting both. :)

Comment: I am using eclise 2020-03 and there I don't see build automatically option as shown in above screenshot

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have added an "Program"-based builder to the project that compiles/translates the files into `.java`.

If you open the builder - via project properties -> `Builders` -> `Edit...` builder - then you can open the `Refresh` tab - se below.

[image: Refresh tab of the Builder Dialog]

Here you can then select which resources to refresh when this particular build is run... E.g. all resources in `target/generated-sources/xyz`...

Comment: Thanks, that's a good tip. In my case, it is actually a maven based process that is configured with m2e. I wish that these types of actions could be specified cleanly in the `pom.xml` so that each dev didn't have to setup the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

with "build automatically" option checked, it is not building on clean. What I had to do extra is, clear all error logs and Problems, then the correct setup can produce class files.